# REST API Key is alowing to send notifications to all devices, how to prevent this?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am making system, when users from iOS is subscribing to push notifications, using different channels. Each group should receive notifications only targeted to this group.
I found, that just knowing REST API Key, you are able to send notifications to any devices, despite on subscribed channel. 
All you need is just to replace

```
    "where": {
      "channels": "My_group_1"
    }
```

to

```
    "where": {
      "deviceType": "ios"
    }
```

My iOS app will be distributed in the App Store. Each iOS device will be subscribed to the group channel push notifications. Administrators of each group will send push notifications only to the members of this group via REST API calls. I just found, that anybody smart enough can modify this call and be able to send notifications not only to channel members, but to all devices.
How to prevent this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you need? WHat is doing the preventing? under what circumstances are you preventing it? are you preventing some other application or preventing it in your own application?

Comment: Sorry, I need to add an aditional explanations. My iOS app will be distributed in the App Store. Each iOS device will be subscribed to the group channel push notifications. Administrators of each group will send push notifications only to the members of this group via REST API calls. I just found, that anybody smart enough can modify this call and be able to send notifications not only to channel members, but to all devices.

Comment: We can't help you when you just describe your code. Please actually add your code *to your question* (edit it and add it there, don't reply in comments) and show us instead :)

Comment: This is kinda what we need in order ot help you out: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You implement access rights on your server. There are a couple of options depending on your special case.

- If you have accounts, you can group them into separate groups. Those who are allowed to use "ios", and those who aren't. When somebody sends `deviceType=ios` you check with their account if they are allowed. If they aren't, your API returns an error
- You distinguish between the two rights with different API tokens. Same as before. Check if the token is allowed and proceed, otherwise return an error.
- If nobody should be allowed to use `{"deviceType": "ios"}`, you check that `deviceType` does not contain `ios`. If it does, your API returns an error. No need for different access groups in this case.

You probably should not allow the client to talk to the Push API directly anyway.